# How do I check from Journey Builder if a record exists in SFDC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, automationstudio

I have a requirement where in I need to check from Journey Builder if a record exists in SFDC (we have marketing cloud connect in place to connect to SFDC).

1. We have an Automation that checks an FTP server for file drops (The
   file will contain Lead information). Whenever there's a file drop,
   it fires and updates a Data Extension.
2. The Automation is an entry criteria for a Journey. The first step in
   the journey is to check if there's an identical Lead record in the
   Salesforce side.
3. If there's no identical Lead, we need to create a Lead record in the
   Salesforce side.

I need to figure out a way to check from the Jouney if there's a record in the Salesforce side.

Could you please suggest me an approach to check from the Journey if an identical Lead record exists in the Salesforce side.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Marketing Cloud connect, I would import the lead object (if you are not using data stream). You can then use this as contact data to as an entry condition for the journey.

1. Import Lead Object
2. Create A new Table for a data extension that will be populated with a query that compared the value in the DE with the import field , with a boolean field "IsSalesForceLead"
3. Write a query to populate the DE created in 2
4. When configuring the entry source , select the data extension created in 2 with Filter conditions `

> "IsSalesforceLead" = false

You might want to include steps that update the 2. so that if they become a lead while the contact in the journey, they get eject. ie set Goal "IsSalesforceLead" = true
`

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Automation in place anyway, I would write a script activity that checks the lead object in the sfdc directly. however, this depends on the number of records we are talking about.